# "Collection was modified" error attempting to Enumerate Files in a Bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-bundling

I am getting a tricky error on an MVC page that only occurs when multiple users are on the site.

The error I get is

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

The error occurs on the line that attempts to render a javascript file Bundle.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/js")
```

The associated code in /app_start -> BundleConfig.cs -> RegisterBundles is pretty standard:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/js").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
            "~/Scripts/jQuery.Buzz/jquery.buzz.js"
        ));
```

The error only seems to occur when there are multiple users on the site at once.  I managed to reproduce the problem locally by creating multiple tabs in multiple browsers and hitting them as quick as I can.

I've searched and haven't been able to find anyone else with a similar error.  The error implies that the a collection is being modified while being looped over.  I can't see how the collection of files to be added to the bundle could be changing as the collection is being enumerated.

The Stack trace is as follows:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) +56
   System.Collections.Generic.Enumerator.MoveNextRare() +14277518
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.EnumerateFiles(BundleContext context) +266
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +38
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +61
   System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath) +214
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets) +410
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +35
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\..\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:13
```

The server was not particularly overloaded at the time the errors occurred. I have monitoring software on the server that showed the CPU and memory at normal levels while the errors were generated.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

UPDATE: After some further searching I discovered that the Bundle was being updated programmatically in the Controller.

```
  BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("~/Scripts/js").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-{version}.js");
```

It turns out this didn't need to be added programmatically so I have included it in the BundleConfig file and the site seems to be behaving now.

Comment: The `Scripts.Render()` function shouldn't cause such exception. Post the content of the BundleConfig.cs file to see if there is anything wrong there, specifically the `~/Scripts/js` path.

Comment: the error you got happens if you were using foreach() statement on a collection and collection changes within the execution of foreach() .

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I am about to try replacing the {version} wildcard in BundleConfig.cs with explicit versions to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Getting rid of all the wildcards from the BundleConfig.cs didn't fix the issue.  It seemed like it improved things but further testing showed the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your bundle config file under app_start

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js1").Include("~/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js","~/js/jquery-ui.js"));
    }
```

the "~/bundles/js1" is the name of the bundle.

in your view add this line tor render the scripts into the view.

```
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js1")
```

that should work fine... just don't forget to change the included js file name and the name of the bundle

Comment: Thanks Roy. That's what I've already done.  I've added some more details to my question to clarify.